# Debug statements are not being called in log4j

Tags: log4j

This is my above log4j.properties file ,

```
log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1

# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=${user.home}/MYWEB/MYWEB.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

I have these statements:

```
logger.info("The middleware url is"+Request.getSecurityHeader().);
logger.debug("Inside the Jai method");
logger.debug("The middleware url is"+URL);
```

Why am I getting this line only

> The middleware url is

Why is the debug not being executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace this line at the top

```
log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1
```

with

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, A1
```

I hope problem will be solved, You can also add following statement after replacing the above line.

```
log4j.appender.aar.Threshold=DEBUG
```